# Как получить дату в Javascript один месяц назад

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
var d = new Date();

var from = d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
```

Этот код возвращает мне числа такие как 1425981709407

Comment: Возможно это поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `setMonth()` меняет сам объект типа `Date`, при этом возвращая timestamp этого объекта (количество милисекунд, прошедших с 1970-01-01).

Вам нужно всего лишь игнорировать значение, возвращаемое `setMonth()`, а просто использовать `d`:

```
var d = new Date();
var from = d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
alert(from); // число, такое как 1425981709407

alert(d); // Tue Mar 10 2015 10:09:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

Comment: спасибо работает

Comment: Как использовать String.Format() в JS.                                                   div = String.format("&date1={0}&date2={1}",from,to);

Comment: Используйте конкатенацию: `var div = '&date1=' + from + '&date2=' + to;`. 
Если `from` и `to` — объекты типа `Date`, то преобразуйте их в строку в соответствию с желаемым форматом, например: `var div = '&date1=' + from.toISOString() + '&date2=' + to.toISOString();`

Comment: да, работает...

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `d` при это получит новое значение.

т.е. достаточно так:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
```

Comment: А сработает ли это в январе?

Comment: @VladD сработает, см. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7937257/1159507

Comment: Хм, и правда, работает. Не ожидал, если честно.