# Вывести будущий месяц react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нужно сделать так, чтобы выводилась сегодняшняя дата + 3 месяца

Comment: Сегодня 01.12.2022, значит вам надо вывести 01.03.2022.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить дату в Javascript один месяц назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415543/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%86-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой date-fns, метод addMonths https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/addMonths